# What is default download path for Pytorch models on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, pytorch, torchvision

What is default download path for Pytorch models (from torchvision) on MacOS?

I can't see anything in home dir `ls -la ~/ | grep torch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the path it displayed when you first download the pre-trained weights for that model, something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's under `~/.cache/torch/hub/checkpoints/`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the download location with the `model_dir` arg. The [default behaviour](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/hub.html#load_state_dict_from_url) is:

```
The default value of `model_dir` is ``<hub_dir>/checkpoints`` where 
`hub_dir` is the directory returned by :func:`~torch.hub.get_dir`.
```